# RSS Feed Viewer Sharepoint 2010 Webpart stopped working

Tags: web-part

I have a RSS view webpart in SharePoint 2010 portal, till last day it was working fine. Now it's throwing the error:

> The requested RSS feed could not be displayed. Please verify the settings and url for this feed. If this problem persists, please contact your administrator.

We didn't have any proxy server, and RSS feed link is not a Secured HTTP. The RSS feed is working fine, I can able to view the data through browser. Please help me to sort it out.

Comment: Please give some strategy for debugging.

Comment: When you checked the feed from a browser, did you do that on the server?

Comment: ya i did see the feed

Answer (score 0):

In the old days before SharePoint 2010, we used to have a similar problem.  It was because anonymous access to SharePoint was turned off.  Not sure if that's still a problem in 2010.